# boost::filesystem::create_directories: Function not implemented

Tags: logging, boost

I'm trying to run the "rotating text file" log example in ubuntu 18.04 using Boost 1.76.0,
the compilation is done successfully but when I try to run the code it gives me the following error:

FAILURE: boost::filesystem::create_directories: Function not implemented: "/test/build/logs"

The code is:

```
//#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK 1

#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_file_backend.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

using boost::shared_ptr;

enum { LOG_RECORDS_TO_WRITE = 10000 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        // Create a text file sink
        typedef sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_file_backend > file_sink;
        shared_ptr< file_sink > sink(new file_sink(
            keywords::file_name = "file.log",                       // file name pattern
            keywords::target_file_name = "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%5N.log",   // file name pattern
            keywords::rotation_size = 16384                         // rotation size, in characters
            ));

        // Set up where the rotated files will be stored
        sink->locked_backend()->set_file_collector(sinks::file::make_collector(
            keywords::target = "logs",                              // where to store rotated files
            keywords::max_size = 16 * 1024 * 1024,                  // maximum total size of the stored files, in bytes
            keywords::min_free_space = 100 * 1024 * 1024,           // minimum free space on the drive, in bytes
            keywords::max_files = 512                               // maximum number of stored files
            ));

        // Upon restart, scan the target directory for files matching the file_name pattern
        sink->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();

        sink->set_formatter
        (
            expr::format("%1%: [%2%] - %3%")
                % expr::attr< unsigned int >("RecordID")
                % expr::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp")
                % expr::smessage
        );

        // Add it to the core
        logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);

        // Add some attributes too
        logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp", attrs::local_clock());
        logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("RecordID", attrs::counter< unsigned int >());

        // Do some logging
        src::logger lg;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < LOG_RECORDS_TO_WRITE; ++i)
        {
            BOOST_LOG(lg) << "Some log record";
        }

        return 0;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "FAILURE: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The CMakeList.txt file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set (CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

project ("cpMain")

# we will use static libs
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)  # link statically
#ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK)  # or, link dynamically

# Boost::log required Boost version >= 1.76.0 
find_package(Boost 1.76 COMPONENTS log REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# Define Sources
set(SRC_FILES
    "main.cpp"
    )

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (cpMain
                        ${SRC_FILES})
                        
# Link your application with OpenCV libraries
target_link_libraries (cpMain
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

Thanks for the help,

Luis

Comment: Welcome to SO! Interessting question, but please remove some unnecessary clutter from your sources like the comments in the CMakeLists. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example